# SemPlot, problems showing lines in CFA Plot of Lavaan

Tags: r, plot, r-lavaan, semplot

I'm trying to make a SemPlot. The only problem I've got is that the plot shows some strange lines, next to the labels of the manifest variables. In the photo you can see what is my problem. The code I ran is this:

```
semPlot::semPaths(lid_des_fa, residuals=T, what="std", label.cex=1, edge.label.cex=0.5, fade=FALSE,
              intercepts=F, curveAdjacent = TRUE,title=F, layout="tree2",sizeMan=7, 
              curvePivot=TRUE,borders=FALSE, nCharNodes=0, nCharEdges=0,
              nodeLabels=paste0("LD",c(2,6,11,12,13,14,3,5,7,9,1,4,8,10)))
```

PLOT and strange lines:

[image]

Comment: the answer was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding threshold `= FALSE` in `semPath()` function.

For example:

```
semPaths(fit1, "std", title = FALSE, thresholds = F)
```